# How to close a MatBlazor MatMenu programmatically

Tags: c#, blazor, matblazor

I want to use a MatBlazor Matmenu component.
It can be opened through the 'OpenAsync' Method, but how can it be closed programmatically?

As can be seen in https://blazorfiddle.com/temp/ff5c7660-dd79-44a6-9135-1d19b83bcbf0 the menu opens when clicking on the button, but does not close when clicking elsewhere. So I would like to close it from code.

Edit: The menu does close when clicking elsewhere on the page (see answer below), but I really am looking for a way to close it from code.

Comment: I attempted to use your BlazorFiddle but it did not work. Please update your fiddle and I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

No Repro.

> but does not close when clicking elsewhere.

But it does.

It does not appear to work in your Fiddle because the page below the button is only 1 pixel high. There is nothing to click.

Add a few `<p></p>` pairs above `@code` and then click just right of the opened Menu. It will close.

[BlazorFiddle here](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/porqf6vv)

Comment: I tried your suggestion in BlazorFiddle, but no success. 
Apart from that, I really want to close it from code.

Comment: It worked in the Fiddle for me....  Try https://blazorfiddle.com/s/porqf6vv

Comment: It does indeed but needs clicking right next to the menu in your example. In my App I Use the menu in a NavBar on top, but it does not open when I click in another component on the screen.
Anyway, I really am looking for a solution in code: I Want to make a menu that automatically opens (via Mouseover event) and closes again when the user moves to another part of the UI (via mouseout event).

Comment: I looked at the source, there are no CloseXXX methods. I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: I tought so but was hoping someone knew of a way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

MatMenus have a `CloseAsync()` method that should do the opposite of opening it.

https://www.matblazor.com/Menu unfortunately does not include a list of methods in its documentation for MatMenu.

Comment: It occurs to me that CloseAsync() was not available to OP.